# Why does throwing an exception after Ctrl+C freezes the console?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, cmd, mingw

I came across this problem while writing a console application with input parsing in C++11 for a school assignment.

I'm using the [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/latest/download) compiler on Windows 10. When I run this program from cmd and hit Ctrl+C, the command line freezes, keeping the process running, not responding to console inputs.

**Minimal, Complete, and (Verifiable?) example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    getline(std::cin, line);

    if (!std::cin.good()) {
        std::ostringstream message;
        message << "Unexpected input stream state \"" << std::cin.rdstate() << "\".";
        throw std::invalid_argument(message.str());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It HAS worked<sup>1</sup> once or twice, but I could not reproduce it, because it broke the second time I ran it (without recompiling or changing anything). I'm not sure if anyone can reproduce the problem.

If I delete the `throw`, it works.

Also, if I output a text with `cout` right after `getline`, it works too.

Why is this happening?

<sup>1 *working* - the expected behaviour is to immediately close down the program when hitting Ctrl+C (without throwing the invalid argument exception).</sup>

Comment: Why are you throwing? That crashes the program. I mean maybe it makes sense but you are at the top level anyway so why not just print a message and call `std::exit`?

Comment: @AluanHaddad It's a "Minimal, Complete, and (Verifiable?) example".

Comment: I agree. I was just asking what the reasoning behind it was. I am curious

Comment: @AluanHaddad I have a function to read integers from a line, throwing exceptions if the entered input format is incorrect, which are then handled by a try-catch block in the calling function, or somewhere.

Comment: But the code is in main, there is no try catch around it. Anyway, I compiled with MSVC++ 2017 (Windows 10, don't have GCC installed) and it does what I expect it to. It causes a crash and "Windows tries to find a solution..."

Comment: There is no guarantee Ctrl-C works universally the same for all programs.  That key combination can be intercepted by the program to do whatever the program wants to do with it.

Comment: @Paul But his program doesn't try to intercept Ctrl-C.

Comment: Not his program, the underlying library being used.

Comment: @Paul Well, as it's MinGW, this will be the MSVC runtime, and I have never seen behaviour like this with that library.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I compiled it with MVSC and it worked for me too. I have MinGW configured as my compiler in CodeBlocks, downloaded from the link mentioned in the post, and I run the program with cmd.

Comment: Well, use MSVC++, you are on Windows after all, and it is the officially supported compiler (You might also try updating GCC). Also, just so someone says it, this is a very poor way to validate input.

Comment: @csirmazbendeguz If you are curious, when it "freezes", attach to the process with a debugger and use "break" to temporarily see what function(s) are being run.  That will tell you what is frozen.

Comment: The console control handler executes on a separate thread that's started by the Windows session server, csrss.exe, in response to a request it receives from the console host process, conhost.exe. The default handler calls `ExitProcess`, but this is inherently out of sync with the `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` call in `getline`.

Comment: You can set your own C runtime `SIGINT` handler via `signal` or a low-level control handler via `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. In your handler you can set a Windows Event, which your UI thread can wait on for 100 ms or so when a read fails.  If you're calling `ReadConsole`, then you can also call `GetLastError` to check for `ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED` to gate waiting on the Event. In Windows 8+, you won't see this error code with a call that uses `ReadFile` instead of `ReadConsole` because they rewrote the low-level console I/O; broke this documented behavior; and have yet to fix it.